# How do I return a single member of a model association array?

Tags: ember.js

I have a hasMany relationship that I'd like to select a single member from based on a member's property value.

The example is a certificate has multiple issuances and I would like to get the most recent based on the start property. But even when I try to return just the first item in the association I can't get anything to show in the template.

```js
App.IssuanceModel = DS.Model.extend({
 start: DS.attr(),
 end: DS.attr()
});

App.CertificateModel = DS.Model.extend({
  issuances: hasMany('issuance', {async: true}),

  currentIssuance: function(){
    this.get('issuances').then(function(issuances){
      return issuances.objectAt(0);
    });
  }.property('issuances.@each.start')
});
```

And in the certificate template

```
{{currentIssuance.start}}
```

I get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kingpin2k's answer sent me down the right path. I can use the `firstObject` property on a sorted array of issuances, so instead of trying to calculate the `currentIssuance` I can sort:

```js
sortedIssuances: function(){
  return this.get('issuances').sortBy('start');
}.property('issuances.@each.start'),
```

And in the template just get the first object.

```
{{sortedIssuances.firstObject.start}}
```

Answer (score 1):

your return is happening asynchronously so it's really returning undefined since you don't return anything.  Just use `firstObject`.

```
{{issuances.firstObject.start}}
```

Comment: Doesn't address my issue of getting the most recent issuance

Comment: It addressed your question "How do I return a single member of a model association array?"